# Ist Ganerburg eine historische, mögliche Form von Ganerbenburg?

Tags: word-usage, etymology, single-word-request, vocabulary

Eine [Ganerbenburg](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ganerbenburg)

> ist eine meist größere Burganlage, die gleichzeitig von mehreren Familien oder Familienzweigen bewohnt und verwaltet wurde.

Der Duden kennt nur [diese Schreibweise](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Ganerbenburg).

Sucht man jedoch vermeintlich vertippend nach [Ganerburg](https://www.google.com/search?&q=Ganerburg) finden sich relativ erstaunlich viele Treffer. Darunter sind solche, von denen man annehmen müsste, solche Feinheiten zu beachten, zu unterscheiden und korrekt zu verwenden:

So zum Beispiel die Seite des Schlosses Hohenentringen:

> [DIE HERREN](http://www.hohenentringen.de/unser-haus/4/index.html)
>
> Als erster Besitzer wird um 1075 Adalbert van Antringen genannt. Später gehörte die Burg den Herren von Entringen, den Grafen von Zollern, den Markgrafen von Baden, den Pfalzgrafen von Tübingen, den Grafen und Herzögen von Württemberg sowie ab 1877 den Freiherren von Ow. **Im 15. Jahrhundert war Hohenentringen eine Ganerburg, das heißt eine von mehreren Familien in Erbengemeinschaft bewohnte Burg** mit den Mitbesitzern Herter von Dusslingen, von Stadion, von Güttlingen, von Ehingen und von Wehingen. In der historischen Gaststube befinden sich die Wappen von zwanzig Besitzerfamilien.

*Ganerburg* geht leichter über die Zunge und flüssiger über die Tastatur als *Ganerbenburg*, zumal den meisten eine "[Ganerbschaft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ganerbschaft)" nicht mehr viel sagen dürfte. Dennoch klingt neben der Trefferzahl im Netz das Wort Ganerburg nicht zu fremd für zum Beispiel mittelalterlichen Sprachgebrauch.

Bei einer [Korpussuche über Google-ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/interactive_chart?content=Ganerburg%2CGanerbenburg&year_start=1400&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=2) fällt auf, dass *Ganerburg* [schlicht unerfasst](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Ganerburg%2CGanerbenburg&year_start=1800&year_end=2020&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CGanerbenburg%3B%2Cc0) zu sein scheint.
Allerdings trifft die auch für Ganerbenburg vor ca 1840 zu und ebenso scheinen beide Begriffe gar nicht in fremdsprachiger Literatur auf.

> [image]

Bei aller Vorsicht gegenüber solchen Ergebnissen – auch andere Korpora sich für diese Wörter nicht begeistern zu scheinen– : laut ngram-Viewer scheint selbst *Ganerbenburg* ein anachronistisches Wort zu sein?

Handelt es sich bei *Ganerburg* um eine weit verbreitete Fehlschreibung oder ist dies ein zulässiges und historisch *belegtes* Wort?

Comment: Keine sprachliche Autorität, aber u.U. eine interessante Info: Google-Ngram findet [keinen einzigen Treffer für Ganerburg](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Ganerburg%2CGanerbenburg&year_start=1800&year_end=2020&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CGanerbenburg%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: @Marzipanherz Stimmt. Aber anscheinend werden *beide* Wörter auch gar nicht in Fremdsprachen erfasst, und vor 1840 auch *keines* im "Deutsch"-Korpus. Diese Form scheint also gemäß ngram ohnehin anachronistisch zu sein. Allerdings sind Nachschlagewerke per Google oft nur schlecht erfasst (dark).

Comment: Dass Schloß heißt *Hohenentringen* (wie richtig im Zitat) - Schön, wenn du in einer Frage nach *Silben-Verschlucken* Silben verschluckst ;)

Comment: Im Grimm'schen Wörterbuch findet sich der Begriff "Ganerburg" nicht. Hier gibt es nur verschiedene Wortkombinationen die von [Ganerbe](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&hitlist=&patternlist=&lemid=GG00662#XGG00662) abgeleitet sind. In dieser historischen Quelle ist somit kein Beleg für das Wort zu finden.

Answer (score 1):

*Ganerburg* ist ein Fehler.

Sehr selten, aber möglich, ist *Ganerbburg* (mit doppeltem b, aber ohne en), normal und richtig ist nur *Ganerbenburg*.

Bei Sebastian Münster in der Kosmographey findet sich der seltene Singular *Ganerb* in der Beschreibung des Ulmener Maars. Dort haust angeblich ein Seeungeheuer (ähnlich dem Ungeheuer von Loch Ness) und jedesmal wenn es gesichtet wird, sirbt ein Ganerb auf der benachbarten Burg.